# Enable screen auto-rotate for specific applications but not globally?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s, auto-rotation

So I'd like to enable screen auto-rotation for YouTube and Chrome, but not for other anything else. How do I do this?

I use a Galaxy S5.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a 3rd-party app like [Smart Rotator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rotator_t&hl=en)?

> Are you tired of switching auto-rotate setting back and forth? This
>   tool can help you auto switching it.
>
> You can set auto-rorate/portrait/landscape setting for each app, when
>   you open those apps, it will help you set screen orientation to auto,
>   portrait, landscape automatically.